# MySQL Database Search Strings - Partial words

Tags: php, mysql

Is it possible to search for results as partial words?

For example...
I am currently looking up 2 fields in a basic form  Brand and Name

How do i code the table so that i can search for "Hei" and "Tom Sou"  and not have to search for Tomato Soup?

Can someone show me an example?

Current code

```
<?php
$connect = mysql_connect($dbServer,$dbUsername,$dbPassword);
if(!$connect){
    die('Could not connect: '.mysql_error());
}

?>

<form action="" method="post">  
Brand <input type="text" name="Brand" />Item <input type="text" name="Item" /><input type="submit" value="Submit" />  
</form>  
<?php

$Brand = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Brand']);   
$Item = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST['Item']);     

$sql = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE item_brand LIKE '%".$brand."%' AND item_name LIKE '%".$item."%'"; 
$r_query = mysql_query($sql); 

echo ('<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Brand</td><td>Item</td></tr>');
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r_query)){  
        echo '<tr><td>' .$row['item_ID'].'</td>';  
        echo '<td>' .$row['item_brand'].'</td>';    
        echo '<td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td></tr>';    
    }  
echo ("</table>");
?>
```

Comment: Your current code has also syntax errors

Comment: mysql_extesion is deprecated, you better not use it all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could search for whitespaces in the search word and replace them with % signs, so "Tom Sou" gets replaced with `Tom%Sou`, which in the whole query would lead to `... WHERE item_name LIKE '%Tom%Sou%' ...`.

Note that depending on your database solution you need to do a case-insensitive select / Like.

EDIT : Please make sure to use PDO or mysqli instead of the deprecated mysql module, as it may not be as secure as the newer soultions and will finally get removed from PHP. Both PDO and mysqli support new database mechanisms like prepared statements, while (at least mysqli) still providing similiar functions.

Answer (score 1):

try using this:

```
$item="Tom Sou";
    $like="'";
    $srtarray=explode(' ',$item);
    foreach($srtarray as $key=>$val){// here you can use implode also 
        $like.="%$val%";
    }
    $like.="'";

$sql = "SELECT * FROM DB WHERE item_brand LIKE '%".$brand."%' AND item_name LIKE  $like";
```

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the code according to your needs as i think: This should work for you

```
<?php
$mysqli = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "Password", "DatabaseName");

if (mysqli_connect_errno($mysqli)) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
?>

<form action="" method="post">
    Brand <input type="text" name="Brand" />
    Item <input type="text" name="Item" /><br />
         <input type="submit"  name="submit" value="submit" /></br>
</form>
<?php

if( $_POST['submit']){
//remove tags from user inputs
$Brand  =       strip_tags('%'.$_POST['Brand'].'%');    
$Item   =       strip_tags('%'.$_POST['Item'].'%'); 

//escape mysql injection 
$Brand = $mysqli->real_escape_string($Brand);
$Item = $mysqli->real_escape_string($Item);


$query = "SELECT * FROM  DB WHERE  item_brand LIKE '$Brand' AND  item_name LIKE '$Item'";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

if($res === FALSE) { 
    die(mysqli_error()); // TODO: better error handling
}
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);


echo '<table><tr><td>ID</td><td>Brand</td><td>Item</td></tr>';
        echo '<tr><td>' .$row['id'].'</td>';  
        echo '<td>' .$row['item_brand'].'</td>';    
        echo '<td>'.$row['item_name'].'</td></tr>';    

echo '</table>';


}
```